# Socket Packet Creation For OOP Type Protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, oop

I am working on an application that must used a proprietary protocol.  The protocol is object based and thanks to Stack Overflow I have weeded my way through much of my struggles developing a framework that is both intuitive and efficient. I have read many of the resources on network programming on this site and others and am trying to take to heart most of the information.  One thing that is pointed out regularly is to avoid dynamic memory allocation.  I am struggling working out a way of building my packets efficiently without DMA and remaining as OOP as possible.

A summary of my situation:

At the most abstracted level I want to provide objects that resemble an object on the server side that we are communicating to

```css
class AnObject
{
public:
  AnObject();
  ~AnObject();
  void SetVal(int Val);
  int ReadVal();
private:
  char* Seg_Path;
}
```

Other methods may be implemented and inheritance would come into play to resemble specific objects but thats the idea.  Now these objects are grouped on the server side an access to a specific object requires opening a connection to that group of objects

```css
class AnObject_Group
{
public:
  Connect(char* ConnectData);
private:
  int ConnectionID;
  struct ConnectionSpecificData;
};
```

Now there is one more level of abstraction a sort of Socket i created.

```css
class My_Socket
{
public:
  Connect(char* ipAddress);
private:
  int Session_Number;
  SOCKET Socket;
}
```

Please note I have left lots of details of the classes out because my question is specifically about higher level structuring.  I have left the Send Recv methods out because that is a part of my question.

Now if AnObject issues a read it has to build a small packet an send it through AnObject_Group who would place some information in front and send it through My_Socket.  There are several other issues that come into play.  The server can be quite slow to respond so I am attempting to do this ASync.  I intend to have one thread who works all my My_Socket and handles there send/recv through the WinSock but I have to ensure any message/buffer works with this.  The other issue I struggle with is its not always the same structure i.e. it could go AnObject->AnObject_Group->AnObject_Group->My_Socket and further more the data put infront at each stage is not fixed its usually decided when the data is put in front so AnObject doesnt know how much data AnObject_Group needs to add and how much My_Socket needs to add.

I am not even sure what order to build these packets in should I send a message to My_Socket saying I want to send then let My_Socket assemble the packet or do I build the packet from AnObject who calls a method in AnObject_Group who calls a method in MySocket.  Should my buffer lie in My_Socket or buffers in every AnObject(there may be many of these)

Sorry if my question is vague im a first time asker but i feel like I have read and searched so much and havent been able to find some clear help on this sort of matter. Many post talk about how to send or recv or handle multithread with sockets but I feel this is a bit tricky to get a scalable solution

Thanks Alot

Comment: I suggest that you're running before you can walk. Forget all the Async stuff and just get it working with blocking. I/O. That will drive out all the data format issues. Then see if you have a performance problem, and then change it to Async or whatever once you know you have a problem. It's hard to see how you can know the server will be slow to respond when you haven't built it yet.

Comment: I have implemented a simple non blocking test application but am trying to expand to a more scalable library. My struggles are more related to building a structure of objects that can be passed up a stack each one adding data in front